# requests.get() is doing something different than when I paste the url in my browser

Tags: python-3.x

On Python 3.7 - I am trying to download files from a local server. When I paste the url in my browser it downloads the file nicely. However when I try the following:

```
import requests
url = 'url_for_local_download'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('test.csv', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

the code runs and test.csv is created, however it is full of meaningless symbols, instead of a neat table with numeric values in columns.

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: Tried this too: `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)` it returned: `<http.client.HTTPMessage at 0x2358a012a20>`

Answer (score 0):

What do these meaningless symbols look like? What your code does is making a one-for-one copy of the file content and write it to that csv file. So you'll have tagsin there included like `<html>` or `<body>`.

If you want the

> neat table with numeric values in columns

you'll have to do some parsing of the server-response and/or analyse where the data for your table comes from. For all we know it could come from an API-endpoint. In that case you can process and download that local_url all you want, but there won't be a table with neat numbers in there. The good news is that parsing from an API-endpoint is usually fairly straightforward.

take a look at: https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/intro-to-beautiful-soup this lesson. It explains parsing really good.

Answer (score 0):

You can try read an `http.client.HTTPMessage` object via https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse.read

With this function you can get the message, on your case is for .csv file.